# auto login to sharepoint site which uses windows authenticattion

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint-2010, windows-authentication

How to login to windows authenticated sharepoint site automatically without prompting for credentials using VB.net. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of posting the same question over and over again, post one that contains **all the necessary information** (e.g it is crucial that you want to use VSTS to test a SharePoint solution) and really explains your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Info you've given us is not enough to answer corretly; I hope this helps:

- If it's a custom solution that is in the sharepoint; sharepoint should do this automatically if the user has the appropriate read permissions given in the "User permissions" of the site and there should be a ie trick like:

  1. Go to Internet Explorer options.
  2. Add the SharePoint site to the Trusted Location.
  3. Go to Custom Level and scroll to last option and change it Automatic logon with current username and password.
  4. You may also do it for Intranet Zone if required.
     [reference here](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/automatic-login-sharepoint-for-authenticated-ads-user/)

Like you can understand, it's a client based decision as well, so there should be no fully-operable way to do this.